# Formatting text from database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a textarea on my page where i allow users to write text. To preserve linebreaks that users make while inputting I use:

```
editBox.val().replace(/\r?\n/g, "\r\n");
```

Before the data is uploaded to the database I'm using:

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
```

I do this to preserve as much data as possible without stripping data that might be useful later on. This also helps me to preserve possible formatting options that can be allowed later. I read that this is good practice.

**The problem is**:

When the data is pulled from the database i need to clean it. For that I'm using:

```
function cleanData($data) 
{           
    $data = nl2br($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data,"<br><b><p><i><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6>");
    return $data;
}
```

I'm allowing certain tags that will later be used with a little self-made wysiwyg editor.
However this allows for users to input the following:

```
<p title="some junk here">hax</p>
```

While the title attribute isn't incredibly annoying, other attributes may. I'm not sure whether a user can add class and id attributes, but i can't see why they shouldn't be able to. It also removes anything that looks like a tag such as smilies: `"*<:o) <- happy clown"` would end up looking something like this: `"*"`

I tried using:

```
$data = filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Instead of the cleanData function, however this encodes everything showing my `<br>` converted line breaks as text instead of adding line breaks.

**In short my problem is:**

I can't seem to find a nice way to clean the data so linebreaks/br are preserved while also retaining the possibillity to add some sort of wysiwyg formatting. I don't really care whether it's html tags or something like bbCode: `[b]`.

**My question is as follows:**

Is there a smarter way to do this or is my method fine with a few tweaks?

What would you guys do? :) I would like to avoid using external libraries unless there's a very strong inscentive.

**PS**: I've searched around lot and found no satisfactory answer - I've also spent a long time making this post readable and understandable. I hope I've done it right.

Comment: Why are you doing mysql escaping on data pulled FROM the database? That presumes you'd be stuffing it right back into a query again. As well, real_escape_string() should be the **LAST** operation you do on a string before using it in SQL. Anything else can undo the escaping and leave you vulnerable again.

Comment: I'd go for an external library, why to reinvent wheel?

Comment: @MarcB You're right. AFAIK it would double escape too. That line has been removed, but the main problem is still there. Thank you for this :)

Comment: @Vyktor This is mainly a learning process - the end result may also be commercial and unless the license is completely open then I'd have a problem. Can you recommend one maybe? :)

Comment: Heh, I don't really remember name, I remember that it's the one which is typo3 using (probably it's modification), I tried to look it up on wiki by searching html editors, but wikipedia "is down today", heh.

Comment: @Vyktor disable javascript to view wikipedia :) that should work.

Comment: I just realized that I've never validated input from editor (ah, how young I was, hh), I was always using this http://www.wymeditor.org/ but I've checked and there should be some examples in here http://trac.wymeditor.org/trac how to integrate it safely into your application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6832/discussion-between-vyktor-and-eirinn)

Comment: @Vyktor i appreciate your offer, but it is late and i need my 8 hours of sleep. It is not because i don't take the question seriously that i must decline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

```
editBox.val().replace(/\r?\n/g, "\r\n");
```

That should not be done on client side (JavaScript), but instead on server side (PHP) if you want to be certain that it happens. It can be circumvented by disabling JavaScript or posting from from another site.

Regarding the actual question, I'd go with some pre-made markup language, such as [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29), which is also what's being used here on StackOverflow.

But if you wish to allow for a some custom formatting, you could (as you suggest yourself) use [BB-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) (`[b]`, `[i]`, etc.). The way I'd implement this is to first replace all HTML special characters with their respective HTML entities using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). After this, you could replace things such as `[b]` with `<strong>`, etc.

**Example**

```
$str = "See, [b]evil[/b] input<br/>, <i>etc</i>.";
$str = htmlspecialchars($str);
print $str; // "See, [b]evil[/b] input &lt;br/&gt;, &lt;i&gt;etc&lt;/i&gt;."
$str = str_replace(array("[b]","[/b]"),array("<b>","</b>",$str);
print $str; // "See, <b>evil</b> input &lt;br/&gt;, &lt;i&gt;etc&lt;/i&gt;."
```

To avoid bad markup, you should probably use some regular expressions to replace the BBcode with HTML tags.

Comment: Why not client side? I read that jquery strips linebreaks when using cal and a replace is needed. It doesn't matter for me whether it's client or server, but i'd like to understand why.


Is htmlspecialchars the same as filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); ?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you want to make sure that your data is stored with "\r\n", you have to do it server-side. You can't trust input data. No, `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` is not exactly the same, see [Sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php). It doesn't escape as much. Using `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS` will (as the link also states), be the same as using `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: Thank you @Kristian - Alright, that explains a bit. But if i use the filter, what should i do about line breaks?

Comment: In the 4th line of my code example, I'm replacing all the BBcode with HTML tags. You could do the same with linebreaks, instead of replacing `[b]` with `<strong>`, you would replace "\r\n" with `<br>`.

Comment: Alright and then not do the nl2br() i take it? I'll do some preliminary tests tomorrow and see what i can stitch together. If it comes out right I'll update the post and mark it as answered. Again, thank you.

Comment: I guess you could just use `nl2br` instead of replacing as well. It makes no difference, just make sure you do it _after_ you have used `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6857/discussion-between-eirinn-and-kristian-antonsen)